# MySQL connection timeout issues

Tags: mysql, buffer-pool, query-timeout

We have a PXC environment with three nodes, and each node has 8GB of total RAM, with half of that (4G) dedicated to SWAP, and 3GB configured for Innodb-buffer_pool_size. Our developers have reported random and frequent number of connection timeout issues.

```
Memory Usage:
[root@mysql ~]# free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:              7           1           1           0           4           5
Swap:             4
```

Top Info

```
Tasks: 227 total,   2 running, 225 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 14.4 us,  3.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 81.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  8009172 total,  1618164 free,  1425932 used,  4965076 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  5242876 total,  5242876 free,        0 used.  5818876 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                            
22021 mysql     20   0 8772380 887760  37600 S 100.0 11.1 366:09.21 mysqld                                                                                                                                                                             
 2588 root      20   0  172268   2332   1580 R  20.0  0.0   0:00.10 top                                                                                                                                                                                
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 R   5.0  0.0   7:14.88 rcu_sched                                                                                                                                                                          
  830 root      20   0  178240  36276  21988 S   5.0  0.5 198:34.47 consul                                                                                                                                                                             
    1 root      20   0  191540   4492   2608 S   0.0  0.1  11:43.66 systemd
```

I have a server that was given to me with only 8GB of total RAM< with 4G dedicated to SWAP as shown above (did not setup the system, but was given as is). I have configured the innodb_buffer_pool_size of MySQL to 3GB in addition.

I am running a PXC environment, and all nodes have the same info as noted above. Developers have reported a lot of MySQL timeout connection issues, and I am not sure if this is a result of lack of memory, especially that SWAP has about half total memory dedicated to it. is it possible this might be the possible cause of the issue? Below is the MySQL error log:

```
2018-10-29T07:46:05.831598-00:00 8 [Note] WSREP: wsrep: committed write set (24860)
2018-10-29T07:46:06.871633-00:00 89242 [Note] WSREP: set_query_id(), assigned new next trx id: 332713
2018-10-29T07:46:07.019286-00:00 89228 [Note] Aborted connection 89228 to db: 'slashire_uat' user: 'db-awesome' host: '10.0.1.110' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
2018-10-29T07:46:10.161805-00:00 89243 [Note] WSREP: set_query_id(), assigned new next trx id: 332715
2018-10-29T07:46:15.162479-00:00 89244 [Note] WSREP: set_query_id(), assigned new next trx id: 332717
2018-10-29T07:46:16.147640-00:00 89226 [Note] Aborted connection 89226 to db: 'slashire_uat' user: 'db-awesome' host: '10.0.1.110' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
2018-10-29T07:46:18.148842-00:00 89227 [Note] Aborted connection 89227 to db: 'slashire_uat' user: 'db-awesome' host: '10.0.1.110' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
2018-10-29T07:46:20.161973-00:00 89245 [Note] WSREP: set_query_id(), assigned new next trx id: 332719
```

Comment: Something does not compute.  Please provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` and `SHOW VARIABLES;`.

Comment: And, when you see 100% CPU (like that `top`), run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` to see what query is the hog.  Better yet, turn on the slowlog with `long_query_time=1`.  Later run pt-query-digest.